# Using list comprehension to make a list of new type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to make a function that returns a list of assoc type that I defined from two lists. I think about using list comprehension, but I'm not sure how to get a value from each list.

```
type Assoc k v = [(k, v)]

makeAssoc :: [k] -> [v] -> [Assoc k v]
makeAssoc k v =
   [Assoc k' v' | k' <- k, ???]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ show makeAssoc [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
```

How to implement the `makeAssoc k v`?

Comment: You want a one to one map?

Comment: Do you want it to be like `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`, or every combination from `k` and `v`?  If the former, use `zipWith Assoc k v`, if the latter just put `v' <- v` where you have `???`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined `Assoc k v` as an alias (`type` does not create a distinct type, just gives an existing type a new name - they are still interchangeable) for a list of `(k, v)`. According to the makeAssoc type signature, it returns a list of `Assoc k v`. Which means that it actually returns a list of list of `(k, v)` and that is probably not what you want. Two possible solutions:

Solution 1 - Keep `Assoc k v` as a list of tuples and remove the [] from the type signature of makeAssoc

```
type Assoc k v = [(k, v)]

makeAssoc :: [k] -> [v] -> Assoc k v
```

Solution 2 - Make `Assoc k v` an alias for a tuple (not a list of tuples) and keep the [] in the type signature of makeAssoc

```
type Assoc k v = (k, v)

makeAssoc :: [k] -> [v] -> [Assoc k v]
```

Another problem is that`type Assoc k v` creates the alias `Assoc k v` that you can use on type signatures, but it doesn't create an actual distinct type with a corresponding data constructor. So you can't use `Assoc k v` on the actual implementation of the function. That means we are working with simple tuples and the correct syntax for list comprehensions would be (using the second solution from before):

```
type Assoc k v = (k, v)

makeAssoc :: [k] -> [v] -> [Assoc k v]
makeAssoc ks vs = [(k, v) | k <- ks, v <- vs]
```

But list comprehensions will give you every possible pair using one element from each list. Exampe: `makeAssoc [1, 2] [3, 4]` will result in `[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]`. If you actually want a one to one direct mapping, you should use `zip`.

```
type Assoc k v = (k, v)

makeAssoc :: [k] -> [v] -> [Assoc k v]
makeAssoc ks vs = zip ks vs
```

With this implementation, the result would be `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]`.

Edit:

Going further: when you get more experienced in Haskell, you will learn that you could have written the same thing as:

```
type Assoc k v = (k, v)

makeAssoc :: [k] -> [v] -> [Assoc k v]
makeAssoc = zip
```

Another thing: If you wanted an actual distinct type, you could have used the `data` keyword and the `zipWith` function.

```
data Assoc k v = Assoc k v
    deriving (Show)

makeAssoc :: [k] -> [v] -> [Assoc k v]
makeAssoc ks vs = zipWith Assoc ks vs
```

Or omitting the parameters as before:

```
data Assoc k v = Assoc k v
    deriving (Show)

makeAssoc :: [k] -> [v] -> [Assoc k v]
makeAssoc = zipWith Assoc
```

[Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is a great resource for a beginner and should help you understand all this and much more.

Comment: In your final code snippets you have a couple of unnecessary lambdas.

Comment: You may also want to suggest using `newtype`

Comment: Good point, @SimonGibbons. Don't know what I was thinking. Editing.